# Triple integral over a tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Calculate the triple integral $\iiint_K x \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
> > \mathrm{d}z$ where K is the simplex (tetrahedron) with vertices in
> $(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1)$

So What I did is I found the plane's equation and it is given by $x+y+z=1$ which means

$0≤x≤1, 0≤y≤1-x$ and $0≤z≤1-y-x$

Then:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1dz \int_0^{1-x}dy \int_0^{1-x-y}xdx
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\left(\int_0^{1-x-y}xdx\right)dydx\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\left[ z \right]\mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z\\ 
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{1-x} 1-x-y  \mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_0^1\left[y - \frac{y^2}2 - xy\right]_0^{1-x}\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-2x+1}2 dx\\
&=\left[\frac{\frac{x^3}3 - x^2 + x}2 \right]_0^1\\
&=\frac16\end{align}$$

But the correct answer is $\dfrac1{24}$

Comment: $$\int _0^1\int _0^{1-z}\int _0^{-y-z+1}x\ dxdydz=\frac{1}{24}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have done a calculation mistake. The limits for integration that you have derived is correct.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-y}\int_{0}^{1-x-y}x\,dz\,dx\,dy$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-y}x(1-y-x)\,dx\,dy$$

Substitute $x=(1-v)u$ and  $y=v$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(1-v)^{3}u(1-u)\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{4}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: What do you mean here $x=(1−y)u$?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Make the transformation $(u,v)\mapsto ((1-v)u,v)$. You can also write $x=(1-v)u ,\, y=v$ .

Comment: It's nothing, it's just to make the computation easier but relating to the Beta function. That is on the $x$ integral , we are making the substitution $x=(1-y)u$ . Then the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(1-y)^{3}u(1-u)\,dy\,du$ which is in the beta function form.

Comment: Yeah I get substituted but how did you get $x=(1−y)u$ is kinda my what I'm struggling with

Comment: @Need_MathHelp As I said, if it helps $x=(1-v)u$ , $y=v$ is the change of coordinates that I am making .

Comment: If you mean "why" I substituted that then it is just  to make the computation easier. Forget about the $y$ integral for now . Notice that you have $x\bigg((1-y)-x\bigg)$ as the integrand and $0\to 1-y$ as the limit. So if we substituted $x=(1-y)t$ then I would end up with the integral being $(1-y)^{3}\int_{0}^{1}t(1-t)\,dt$ which is of the form of beta function and is much easier to evaluate.